# Problems with mod_rewrite going from dev to live server

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I just uploaded a new project to the live server, which has a base ubuntu server install (latest LTS version).

I am having some weird problems with mod_rewrite, which works fine on my dev system. On the live server, it runs with no errors in the error.log and correctly finds the files with .php extension, but does not populate the "path_info" GET parameter.

The .htaccess file is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\-_\.]+)(/[A-Za-z0-9\-_\.\/]*)?$ $1.php?path_info=$2 [QSA]
```

What do I need to look for to fix this?

Comment: Can you post the rules write in httpd.conf of dev and live server? your code here is correct, i think it is the server configuration. compare this dev and live server's configuration first.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem - Multiviews was enabled as an option in the apache2 config and this was causing the htaccess rules not to be hit.

Removing multiviews resolved the issue.